# ansible Jinja2 template regex search and return string found

Tags: python, regex, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm trying to search for a specific string from a var and while it finds it, it prints the whole line and not the exact match I'm looking for. I'm running ansible 2.9 
Here is what it finds:
**Interface GigabitEthernet0/1 "outside1", is up, line protocol is up**

And what I'm looking for is everything up to ", or better yet any specific word in that line
Interface GigabitEthernet0/1 "outside1",

Here is my template:

```
'''
    {% for interface in show_interface.stdout_lines[0] %}
    {% if interface | regex_findall('Interface*.*\"\,',multiline=True) %}
    {{interface | string}}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
'''
```

Here is my ansible-playbook task:

```
'''
---
- name: execute firewall interface review
  asa_command:
    commands:
      - show interface | grep up
  register: show_interface

- name: print var data
  debug:
   var: show_interface.stdout_lines

- name: format interface data with template
  template:
    src: firewall_format.j2
    dest: ./firewall_interface_facts.txt
  delegate_to: localhost
'''

Here is the output of show_interface.stdout_lines[0]
"show_interface.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/0 \"\", is administratively down, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/1 \"outside1\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tFull-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/2 \"outside2\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tFull-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/3 \"\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/4 \"\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/5 \"\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/6 \"\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/7 \"statelink\", is administratively down, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface GigabitEthernet0/8 \"folink\", is administratively down, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface Management0/0 \"mgmt\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface Redundant1 \"\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported", 
            "Interface Redundant1.201 \"inside\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "Interface Redundant2 \"management\", is up, line protocol is up", 
            "\tAuto-Duplex(Full-duplex), Auto-Speed(1000 Mbps)", 
            "\tInput flow control is unsupported, output flow control is unsupported"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post `show_interface.stdout_lines`. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).